# Reasoning behind speed of parametric curve formula

Tags: calculus, parametric

The speed of a parametric curve is given by $$\sqrt{(dx/dt)^2 + (dy/dt)^2}$$

Wouldn't this equation just give a very small length of the curve (because of Pythagorean theorem)? Integrating this gives you the length of the curve from t = a to t = b.

In a position graph of 1d motion the tangent line of the curve will give you the velocity. How come in 2d motion the tangent line $dy/dx$ doesn't give you the velocity, but the small length of the curve does?

Comment: Think about this in terms of scales, $t$ is a unit of time and $x,y$ are units of length. Therefore, the quantity in question is in units of length/time (e.g. speed).

Comment: That's not an equation. I guess you mean $v(t)=ds/dt = \sqrt{(dx/dt)^2 + (dy/dt)^2}$?

Comment: In your referenced dimension-one velocity, the comparison quantity ($x$) is a time variable.

Comment: @Gregory I see. So when the length of the curve is 0, the object is not moving. Thanks for the explanation. One more question: What would the tangent line represent? The instantaneous direction of the object?

Comment: I would say it represents the velocity at that point. Whether you think of velocity in terms of $y$ vs. $x$ or $x$ vs. $t$, it is the rate at which you're moving with respect to the variable (whatever name you choose to give it).